# derivative and antiderivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f$ be an infinitely differentiable real valued function. Can any condition be given under which $n$th antiderivative of the $n$th derivative of $f$ is equal to $f$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, solutions of $y^{(2n)}=y$? Look at functions like $f(x)=e^{wx}$ where $w$ is a (complex) number satisfying $w^{2n}=1$. Linear combinations of those functions would also have the same property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f^{(n)}=:g$. There is not "the" $n^{\rm th}$ antiderivative of $g$, but an $n$-dimensional affine space $G$ of them. Two functions in $G$ differ by a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$, and exactly one element in $G$ is $=f$.

There are cases where $f$ has a special property, e.g., being non-constant and bounded. In such a case it may happen that only one element of $G$ has this property, and this element then has to be the $f$ we started with.